# rake assets precompile failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

When I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`, my precompilation fails but I cannot see any specific reason for it.

See this pastebin for my output: http://pastebin.com/zggZyPyM

Comment: Do you have a javascript runtime installed? I encountered a similar error this week when trying to pre-compile assets on a linux VM.

Comment: if zajn's suggestion doesn't work out, you should check your syslog. Precompiling assets takes a lot of memory(more than "rails s") and might be possible that OS is killing off the process due to that.

Comment: Ah! @rubish You are right... running out of memory.

Comment: @jasonlfunk Posted as answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Precompiling assets takes a lot of memory. ~=400mb in my case. It might be possible that OS is killing of the process due to excessive memory usage. You can check the syslog to verify if that is the case.

You can increase the memory of your server to avoid the situation. If that is not possible, I would suggest that you precompile assets on your local system, commit them to the repo and deploy to the server. That way you wouldn't have to compile assets on your server. However you might want to look into ways to delete the previously generated assets somehow and also automate the process.

Answer (score 2):

, but issue was resolvedI tried installing node.js first. And then, ran the following command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. Only then I didn't notice the error.

Initially, I thought it was because of low memory too. Cleaned almost all running applications, but couldn't find a solution. Plus, I opened Ruby as administrator. Not sure if that helped too, but issue was resolved.

Comment: Installing Node.js on windows fixed this issue for me. FYI, this [page](http://ajacevedo.com/2013/using-node-js-as-a-rails-javascript-runtime/) has good info on setting env to use Node.js

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also be resolved by using a node.js JS runtime to precompile assets as it apparently has a lower memory footprint. For Ubunutu 14.04 I needed to run `apt-get install nodejs`, then replace the default js runtime in the `Gemfile` with `gem 'node'`, run `bundle`and finally rerun the precompile. I would caution against precompiling in another location as you may forget to do this after a css or js change, leading to errors.