# rake assets:precompile giving "Error: Out of stack space" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

Hi when I am running rake command it is ending up with "Error: Out of stack space".

can you please help me.
I am using rails 3.2.3 and using spree 1.1.1.

Thanks in advance

I have pasted error log below.

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe C:/Ruby192/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary rake aborted! Error: Out of stack space   (in C:/Users/Aahlad/Documents/new new rails/smockcouture/app/assets/javascripts/application.js) C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:in `extract_result' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-1.2.4/lib/uglifier.rb:101:in `compile' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `block in js_compressor=' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in `block in evaluate' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `each' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `evaluate' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:20:in `block in compile' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>' C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load' C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>' Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary rake aborted! Command failed with status (1): [C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe C:/Ruby192/bin/rak...] C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run' C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>' C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load' C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>' Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Hello can anybody help me please!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253218/rake-assets-precompile-failed/11253929#11253929

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the error but gotta know that it is a windows specific error.I have copied the same application and did rake command in ubuntu and worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same response when I try to precompile using the `ckeditor` gem. The init.js.erb includes other JS files, some of which are already 'compressed' and as a result, the file is essentially one big string of text without any line breaks. If I open it in Komodoedit I get a warning saying the info is truncated because it is too long. Perhaps this is what is happening when Uglifier tries to read and then compress the string data. I don't know of a solution as it only just recently happened to me. Use `rake assets:precompile --trace` to see where the error actually crops up.