# rake assets:precompile - Out of stack space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My rake assets:precompile are not working on production environment, I'm getting "Out of stack space" error

I'm running rake on Windows 7 with 8 GB, so memory is not a problem at all. This guy [rake assets:precompile giving "Error: Out of stack space" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510924/rake-assetsprecompile-giving-error-out-of-stack-space-error) said that running on Ubuntu solved his problem, but I do not plan to do this...

After run a trace I noticed that the precompile always stopped on my application.js, here is the code:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= requeire jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require calendarize
//= require_tree .
```

some days ago it was working, actually the only difference is the calendarize, a gem that I added. But I tried to remove it from application.js and the error continues

I'm on Rails 4 and Ruby 2 - If anyone can help it would be great! Thanks!

EDIT: I didn't had jquery-ui before to! Not using this version on gem file at least: gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.3.0"

EDIT2: Just updated jquery-rails and added jquery-ui-rails, got the same problem. Them tried to remove everything from application.js. Same problem.

Comment: Thanks for point out that, but didn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research a lot, I find out that this is a Windows problem. Don't know why this happens, but I installed an ubuntu develop environment and everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rake assets:clean
```

and next,

```
rake assets:precompile
```

If it's not working yet try like below and trace what is the problem.

```
rake assets:precompile --verbose
```

BTW, I strongly recommend use RoR on the OSX or Ubuntu except for Windows. 
There are various barriers even though you solve this problem..

Cheers, humbroll.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but still getting "Out of stack" space for application.js... :(

Comment: try one more time after remove '//= require_tree .'. That could be a memory bind issue..

Comment: Tried many kinds of combination, the precompile only works without any //=require !! Dafuq!